# Haskell: How to define Binary instance for (BigFloat e)?

Tags: haskell

How do i define a Binary instance for Data.Number.BigFloat?

I've defined an instance for LongDouble by writing:

```
instance Binary LongDouble where
    put d = put (decodeFloat d)
    get   = do
        x <- get
        y <- get
        return $! encodeFloat x y
```

However trying the following doesn't work:

```
instance Binary (BigFloat e) where
    put d = put (decodeFloat d )
    get   = do
        x <- get
        y <- get
        return $! encodeFloat x y
```

GHC gives this error message:

```
/home/usr/Documents/src/Lib.hs:27:18: error:
    • No instance for (Epsilon e) arising from a use of ‘decodeFloat’
      Possible fix:
        add (Epsilon e) to the context of the instance declaration
    • In the first argument of ‘put’, namely ‘(decodeFloat d)’
      In the expression: put (decodeFloat d)
      In an equation for ‘put’: put d = put (decodeFloat d)
   |
27 |     put d = put (decodeFloat d )
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/home/usr/Documents/src/Lib.hs:31:19: error:
    • No instance for (Epsilon e) arising from a use of ‘encodeFloat’
      Possible fix:
        add (Epsilon e) to the context of the instance declaration
    • In the second argument of ‘($!)’, namely ‘encodeFloat x y’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: return $! encodeFloat x y
      In the expression:
        do x <- get
           y <- get
           return $! encodeFloat x y
   |
31 |         return $! encodeFloat x y
```

If I provide a specific type for e, such as Prec500, i get this message :

```
• Illegal instance declaration for ‘Binary (BigFloat Prec500)’
    (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
     where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
     and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
     Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
• In the instance declaration for ‘Binary (BigFloat Prec500)’
```

And using FlexibleInstances compiles, but doesn't result in correctly encoded numbers.

The following also compiles but doesn't encode correctly either:

```
instance Epsilon e => Binary (BigFloat e) where
    put d = put (decodeFloat d )
    get   = do
        x <- get
        y <- get
        return $! encodeFloat x y
```

Comment: What do you mean by “doesn't result in correctly encoded numbers”?

Comment: @leftaroundabout if I use Data.Binary.encode on number as a LongDouble it works perfectly. If I use encode on the same number as a BigFloat i get an error saying "*** Exception: Negative exponent"

Comment: How can you even have “the same number as a `BigFloat`”? If it's a different type it's also a different value. How did you construct the examples in either case?

Comment: @leftaroundabout if i try to encode a number initialized as a BigFloat, simply by writing (3 :: BigFloat Prec500), it gives me the "*** Exception: Negative exponent" error. However, if I instead do (realToFrac (3 :: BigFloat Prec500) :: LongDouble) it encodes fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `BigFloat` seems to be not super-well-done. The problem lies here:

```
> floatDigits (0 :: BigFloat Prec500)
-9223372036854775808
```

(The correct answer should be 500.) I admit I don't fully understand why that is happening; but from the source, the way `floatDigits` is computed is by taking the log of the precision -- but `log` is a thing that happens on `Double`s and `Double` doesn't have enough precision to represent `1e-500`. So that method of computing the digit count seems doomed from the start.

Why do I say I don't fully understand? Well, I see the following in the source:

```
floatDigits (BF m _) =
    floor $ logBase base $ recip $ fromRational $ precision m
```

From my reading, `fromRational` should produce `0 :: Double`. But if that were true, the final value would be `0`, not `minBound`:

```
> floor $ logBase 10 $ recip $ (0 :: Double) :: Int
0
```

So perhaps there is some dodgy rewriting going on or something.

Anyway, a proper implementation of this type should work differently -- e.g. by having a more informative class than `Epsilon` that can report the precision as a base and exponent. (Another possible idea would be to have `floatRadix` return `recip precision` and `floatDigits` return `1`, but that has some oddities around what should happen if the precision is not the reciprocal of a whole number.)

Comment: The fact that `floor $ 1/0` produces `0` is itself a bit dodgy! I'd consider `maxBound` a saner result for this.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm pretty sure that what's actually happening there is that `floor (1/0)` is `2^1024`. That's `0` in `Int`-land but non-zero in some other types. That seems fairly reasonable (if a bit unfortunate for `Int`s) to me, given the maximum finite value of a `Double`. On the other hand, `minBound` -- which is what OP observes -- is Right Out.

Comment: Hmmm... this could be "fixed" by making it `2^1024 - 1 - 2^63` instead, but then it would be `maxBound` _only_ for `Int` / `Int64`. An option that would give _something big_ for all the standard `Int` and `Word` types would be `2^1024 - 1 - sum [2^(8 * 2^n - 1) | n<-[0..3]]`, but this is getting quite awkward to check. `0` is perhas the more reasonable option after all.